# Image does not show up from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to show an image from my database yet it wont show. I researched and tried different codes that I can understand but it is still no use. Here is my show image php code

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_tocode="db_tocode"; // Database name 

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database:     ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id = '$id';";

 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['image'];


?>
```

and here is the link to show the image to the site.

```
     <img src="showimage.php?id=<?php echo $id;?">">
     <div class="text-style"></div>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get nothing as result, or you get "empty image icon"? Maybe your path to images is just wrong

Comment: In the img tag there is an extra double quote. Are you sure that the image field is of tipe binary or varbinary?

Comment: Are u saving the entire image in DB or just the path ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The first script assume that the entire image is in the dB field.

Comment: I get an empty image icon changed and checked the path again and again yet nothing appears. Btw, the image is saved in the database with a blob type

Comment: What type has the id column?

Comment: @JohnnyGraber its INT

Comment: Basic debugging in such cases, as told thousands of times before on the net: Comment out the `header` call, and then call `showimage.php?id…` in your browser directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your id column is not a string you should remove the qutes around `$id`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id = $id;";
```

A good way to debug problems with missing data is o add a print statement after every sql-query. You can then copy and paste the exact statement to your database console and see what result you get and where exactly the data no longer matches your expectation.